# How many steps to mate the only king with all pieces?

Tags: analysis, problems, checkmate

Suppose Black has only one king in its initial place and White has all 16 pieces in their initial places. How many steps does it take to ensure a checkmate? And what are all solutions?

Now that White changes his position with Black. White has only one king. Then How many steps does it take to ensure a checkmate? And what are all solutions?

Comment: I forgot to add 'at least'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first question: It takes **6 moves** to mate the black king. 
The only move is **1.e2-e4**. All other white moves would take more than 6 moves... Also after 1.e2-e4 there are a lot of variations to long to post it right here.

The simplest way is to get the details and answer the second question yourself is using the program **popeye**, see http://sourceforge.net/projects/popeye-chess/

Final remark: There is a well known chess problem with white initial position and black king on h4. How to mate in 3 (white to move...)

Comment: The bKh4 version is (with all white pieces on the board in their starting locations) place bK so that there is mate in 3. This was composed by Sam Loyd in 18something.

Comment: Obviously you can use Popeye (or whatever solving program) also to vary things a bit (like the Kh4 example) if you are curious. A 6# takes only a minute even on my museum computer.